# I have been trying to make this plot to work

Tags: r

I have been trying to come up with a plot and it keeps coming out like this[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZjd7.png)

here is the code I used:

```
comskills <- read.csv('ComputerSkills.csv', header = TRUE,sep = ',')
Level <- subset(comskills, Year %in% c("2019"))
gg <- ggplot(Level)
gg <- gg+geom_point(mapping = aes(x=Age.Group, y=Skill, fill=Skill))
gg <- gg+labs(title= "Which year has the highest level of computer literacy?")
gg
```

[HERE IS THE CSV FILE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CVUHpHO9loAPrxAdjj2BpeOOS0u2KZ2y?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your plot becomes blasted away by the large legend.

When you append:

```
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

I think you will see what the issue was.

kind regards,

Youri